# How to format buttons text with table-cell display inside li?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have dynamic list of buttons (5 in a row) with table-cell display property.I want buttons text to be in the center of table-cell as shown on the pic and doesn't go to next line when page is viewed on iPhone screen.Could you guys tell me what changes should I make to css to achive it?Thanks in advance.

[image]

JavaScript part:

```
<script>



$(document).ready(function () {
$(".myModal").on("click", "li", function(){

 $("li.menu__item").removeClass("menu__item--active");
  $(this).addClass("menu__item--active");

var outlineButtonclass=this.className;

var title = $(this).attr('title');

alert("selected size:"+title);

});

});

</script>
```

Style part:

```
<style>

.menu__element {
border: 1px ;
font-size: 14px;

}

li {
    /* adds table cell around each li */
    display:table-cell;
    width: auto;
    padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}


ul{
    border-spacing: 17px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}


.menu__item--active {
  background: red;
}

</style>
```

UL part:

```
<!-- Modal content -->

<div class="modal-content" style="max-height:calc(100vh - 110px);overflow-y: auto;">


<span class="close">×</span>

<br>

<div class="sizeLabell">Size<span class="form-asterisk"></span></div>


<ul class="square-list" id="square-list">

<li class="menu__item" title="36"><button name="size" type="button" class="menu__element" value="0" title="36">36</button></li>

<li class="menu__item" title="37 1/3"><button name="size" type="button" class="menu__element" value="1" title="37 1/3">37 1/3</button></li>

<li class="menu__item" title="38 2/3"><button name="size" type="button" class="menu__element" value="2" title="38 2/3">38 2/3</button></li>

<li class="menu__item" title="48"><button name="size" type="button" class="menu__element" value="3" title="48">48</button></li>

<li class="menu__item" title="48 2/3"><button name="size" type="button" class="menu__element" value="4" title="48 2/3">48 2/3</button></li><br>

<li class="menu__item" title="49 1/3"><button name="size" type="button" class="menu__element" value="5" title="49 1/3">49 1/3</button></li>

</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to your LI element's CSS.

```
li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I made your suggested change but now the 5th tabel-cell passes the iphone screen view size! Also there is no equal amount of space above and below tabel-cell text(same amount of space on right and left side of text)?How to decrease gap between the two rows?I want my table cells look like lower part of above pic.

Comment: You can set the max-width of the UL parent element, then use media queries to control the width of the element.

Comment: What should be value of max-width for UL? I want 5 elements in a row and fit screen view with equal amount space around each tabel-cell text!